# Headers and imakeidx two-columns

Tags: header-footer, indexing

I have 2 questions about the layout of my indices & for my index headers :

1. I don't understand why the `no indent first` or the `no page break` between the title & the index prologue just after react correctly in a one-column index but not in a two-column index (see my example) ;
2. Why the `headsepline` appear on the head first page of the chapter Index ? This is not his place ;

Can you help me solve these questions or one of them ?

Thank You.
Here my MWE where you can see the difference between the normal behavior of the main matter & the one-column index *versus* the two-columns index :

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode 
% !TEX TS-program = arara
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,markcase=noupper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\indexsetup{level=\section, toclevel=\section, othercode=\footnotesize, headers={\indexname}{\indexname}, firstpagestyle=scrheadings, noclearpage}
\makeindex[title=Index A, columns=2, columnsep=7pt, columnseprule]
\makeindex[name=ici, title=Index B, columns=1]

\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem Ipsum}
\section{Lorem}\lipsum[1-6]\index{lipsum}\index{lorem}\index{ipsum} 
\section{Ipsum}\lipsum[7-12]\index[ici]{lipsum}\index[ici]{lorem}\index[ici]{ipsum}

\addchap{Index}\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\indexprologue{\lipsum[5-7]}\printindex[ici]
\indexprologue{\lipsum[1-4]}\printindex
\end{document}
% arara: xelatex
% arara: makeindex
% arara: xelatex
```

ps : I have seen the chapter of the [imakeidx MAN](http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/imakeidx/imakeidx.pdf) about conflict between two-columns & index prologue, but it doesn't help me.

[image: Exemple]

Comment: And if 5 different people answer one of your 5 questions apiece, whose will you accept? The site works best when you ask one question per... well, per question, really. That also helps to keep your questions sufficiently general and specific to be of use to others and findable by others. Please consider focusing this question on one question and asking additional questions if necessary.

Comment: (1) is based on a false premise. It makes no difference whether the index is 2 column or not. To see this, just reverse the order in which the indices are printed. The reason a new page is inserted is because you are starting a new chapter with `\addchap`. If you don't want a new page, don't start a chapter! (2) is what you requested with `firstpagestyle=scrheadings`. If you omit that, the line disappears.

Comment: @cfr you're right, I'll split the question in two or three questions, it will be most efficient & most helpful. thanks for the advice

Comment: you can find the other questions I had removed from this topic here :
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257885/first-last-entries-in-the-index-header-like-a-dictionary & http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257883/index-and-bad-left-header

Comment: @cfr (1) My English is bad, and I express myself badly in this language. Sorry ^^ Reversing, the problem remain the same, my premise isn't false. I change the `lipsum` paragraph in my MWE to be clearer. It's a layout problem with here two consequences : it indent the first paragraph, it shouldn't ; it break the page between section title and paragraph after (here the index preamble), it shouldn't.

Comment: I don't get a page break between the section title and the index preamble. I do get a page break before the title 'Index' because `\addchap` does that.

Comment: More minimal example using standard class: `\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx,lipsum}
\indexsetup{level=\section, toclevel=\section, noclearpage, othercode=\footnotesize, headers={\indexname}{\indexname}}
\makeindex[title=Index A, columns=2, columnsep=7pt, columnseprule]
\makeindex[name=ici, title=Index B, columns=1]` cont.

Comment: `\begin{document}
  \chapter{Lorem Ipsum}
  \section{Lorem}\lipsum[1-6]\index{lipsum}\index{lorem}\index{ipsum}
  \section{Ipsum}\lipsum[7-12]\index[ici]{lipsum}\index[ici]{lorem}\index[ici]{ipsum}
  \chapter*{Index}\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
  \indexprologue{\lipsum[5-7]}\printindex[ici]
  \indexprologue{\lipsum[1-4]}\printindex
\end{document}
`

Comment: @cfr that's true, good observation : with the normal configuration, it solves the problem of page break between title & his paragraph. But I work in koma-script :s the search continues.

Comment: My point was that KOMA is irrelevant: you can reproduce the problem with a more minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

The way that `imakeindex` typesets the index in this situation is essentially

```
\section{Index title}
\begin{multicols}{2}[index prologue text\par\bigskip]
  index stuff
\end{multicols}
```

Any construct of that form has the tendency to allow a page break between the section heading and the following text.  Instead one can move the `\section` command in to the optional argument of `multicols`:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}[\section{Index title}index prologue
  text\par\bigskip]
  index stuff
\end{multicols}
```

keeping the material together.  The code below provides an corresponding redefinition of `theindex` modelled on `imakeidx`'s version, but with above change effected.  As the `\section` command is accompanied by other machinary, a local macro is defined to keep all this information together, and this is deployed in the different senarios for the index.  It works equally well in a `book` or `scrbook`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,markcase=noupper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\indexsetup{level=\section, toclevel=\section, othercode=\footnotesize, headers={\indexname}{\indexname}, firstpagestyle=scrheadings, noclearpage}
\makeindex[title=Index A, columns=2, columnsep=7pt, columnseprule]
\makeindex[name=ici, title=Index B, columns=1]

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{theindex}{%
  \def\myimki@headercode{%
    \imki@maybeaddtotoc
    \imki@indexlevel{\indexname}\imki@indexheaders
    \thispagestyle{\imki@firstpagestyle}}%
  \ifnum\imki@columns>\@ne
    \columnsep \imki@columnsep
    \ifx\imki@idxprologue\relax
      \begin{multicols}{\imki@columns}[\myimki@headercode]
    \else
      \begin{multicols}{\imki@columns}[\myimki@headercode\imki@idxprologue]
    \fi
  \else
    \myimki@headercode
    \imki@idxprologue
  \fi
  \global\let\imki@idxprologue\relax
  \parindent\z@
  \parskip\z@ \@plus .3\p@\relax
  \columnseprule \ifKV@imki@columnseprule.4\p@\else\z@\fi
  \raggedright
  \let\item\@idxitem
  \imki@othercode}
  {\ifnum\imki@columns>\@ne\end{multicols}\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem Ipsum}
\section{Lorem}\lipsum[1-6]\index{lipsum}\index{lorem}\index{ipsum}
\section{Ipsum}\lipsum[7-12]\index[ici]{lipsum}\index[ici]{lorem}\index[ici]{ipsum}

\addchap{Index}\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\indexprologue{\lipsum[5-7]}\printindex[ici]
\indexprologue{\lipsum[1-4]}\printindex
\end{document}
```